# MultibarChart labels at X axis

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, nvd3.js

I´m trying to set my own X axis label, but I´m not able to do it.
I would like to set those(0,1,2,3,4,5) as

['2015/08/07','2015/08/10','2015/08/13','2015/08/16','2015/08/19']

[image]

I have tried addinf these .tickValues propertiy, but without any result, it just puts my first value at the start of the X axis.

```
chart.xAxis
                .axisLabel("Last week information")
                .scale(10)
                .tickValues(['2015/08/07','2015/08/10','2015/08/13','2015/08/16','2015/08/19']);
```

How can I do that?

Comment: How does your data (that is passed into .datum) look like?

Comment: @ovvn this is my datum structure

.datum([
{"key": "Planificando", "values": [{"x": 0, "y": 1}, {"x": 1, "y": 1}, {"x": 2, "y": 2}, {"x": 3, "y": 2}, {"x": 4, "y": 1}, {"x": 5, "y": 1}]} ,                     {"key": "En Proceso", "values": [{"x": 0, "y": 1}, {"x": 1, "y": 1}, {"x": 2, "y": 2}, {"x": 3, "y": 2}, {"x": 4, "y": 1}, {"x": 5, "y": 1}]} , 
          ])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

```
> var dates =  ['2015/08/07','2015/08/10','2015/08/13','2015/08/16','2015/08/19','2015/08/19']
> 
>                 chart.xAxis.tickValues([0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>                 .tickFormat(function(d){
>                     return dates[d]
>                 });
```